# How do I make a copy of the component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 5 in my project. I did pagination with use ngx-pagination . I need to do this pagination top and bottom table. I need to make pagination at the top and bottom of the table. I did it this way

```html
<div class="admin-panel__nav-block navigation-block">
        <app-table-filter-size (valueChange)="valueChange($event)" [size]="size"></app-table-filter-size>
        <pagination-controls class="table-pagination pagination-block" previousLabel="Previous" nextLabel="Next" id="listing_pagination" (pageChange)="pageChange(p = $event)"></pagination-controls>
    </div>

<!--Table --> 
...
<!--Table End --> 
    <div class="admin-panel__nav-block navigation-block">
        <app-table-filter-size (valueChange)="valueChange($event)" [size]="size"></app-table-filter-size>
        <pagination-controls class="table-pagination pagination-block" previousLabel="Previous" nextLabel="Next" id="listing_pagination" (pageChange)="pageChange(p = $event)"></pagination-controls>
    </div>
```

it's working , but it's probably not a good practice, since the same id is used in different places. how can I get rid of duplicate code? What should I do in my situation?

Comment: Do you really need an `id` attribute ? Just remove it, your code is OK.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an `id` to uniquely identify dynamically assigned instead of having hardcoded `id="listing_pagination"`

Have a paginationConfig Array and push configs for each set of data

- *ts file implementation*

```
private paginationConfigs: Array; // define the variable 
this.paginationConfigs = []; //initialize in the ngOnInit lifecycle function
```

Have the below configuration for each dataset probably inside the loop

```
                const pagerConfig = {
                    id: `pager-${value}`, // value could be any unique identifer
                    itemsPerPage: 10,
                    currentPage: 1
                };
                this.paginationConfigs.push(pagerConfig);
```

- *html file implementation*

`<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data| paginate: paginationConfigs[i]" >// data display </tr>`

`<pagination-controls previousLabel="Previous" nextLabel="Next [id]='paginationConfigs[i].id'(pageChange)="pageChange(paginationConfigs[i].currentPage= $event)"></pagination-controls>`

Comment: @Дмитрий If your facing any difficulty with the answer provided please do let me know I can provide you a working jsfiddle